# How to position infinite loops for tkinter and paho-mqtt-client?

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, paho

This is my code

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json
from tkinter import *
from tkmacosx import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.button = Button(frame, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=frame.quit)
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.hi_there = Button(frame, text="Hello", command=self.say_hi)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=LEFT)

    def say_hi(self):
        print("hi there, everyone!")

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
    client.subscribe("$SYS/broker/clients/connected")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    data = json.loads(msg.payload)
    print(data)

root = Tk()

client = mqtt.Client()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()

client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.connect("test.mosquitto.org", 1883, 60)
client.loop_forever()
```

Don't worry too much about what it does right now. What i need to understand is the concept of infinite loops.

I need an infinite loop to keep the tkinter window on the screen. I also need an infinite loop to keep the MQTT client connection alive.

How do i position those infinite loops in my code? If i place the root.mainloop() before the client.loopforever() i only get to the MQTT code when i close the tkinter window. If i place the root.mainloop() after the client.loopforever() the tkinter window shows up when i close the MQTT connection.

The idea is to get messages from the broker and show them in a tkinter window. Please help me understand where to position those two infinite loops.

Comment: Maybe you want to look at [Multithreading](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm). Because that would be my first solution for two parallel running loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an event loop already exists then `loop_forever()` should not be used but `loop_start()`:

```
# ...
root = Tk()

client = mqtt.Client()

client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.connect("test.mosquitto.org", 1883, 60)
client.loop_start()

app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```